# Программное создание Views Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, модули, views

Как правильно создавать представления (views) программно при установке модуля?

Написал свой модуль отложенных товаров, работает как надо, хочу упростить задачу, осталось только создавать специальные представления (views) с нужными настройками.

Core: Drupal 7x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны определить хук [hook_views_default_views](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views/7.x-3.x). По ссылке вы увидите официальную документацию по нём и примеры. Рекомендую создать нужный views, сделать экспорт, полученный код поместить внутрь даного хука. Также рекомендую посмотреть, как он реализован в контриб модулях, например в модуле commerce. А лучше как реализованы они в самом модуле Views (папка modules), например файл node.views_default.inc

Comment: Спасибо за статью и примеры, я так и думал, но не хватало посмотреть примеров :)

Comment: добавил ещё где посмотреть примеры. спасибо здесь говорят: отметить правильный ответ или стрелочкой вверх